# iOS's LLDB's P command not printing frame variable

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

Lets say I want to do a

```
p uiTextFieldObj.frame
```

it will say error: property

```
'frame' not found on object of type 'UITextField *'
```

Is there any tricks I can do so I can get this to show?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do this:

```
p (CGRect)[uiTextFieldObj frame]
```

As of Xcode 4.5.2, printing properties in lldb using the dot syntax only seems to work for properties of objects defined in your app, not for properties defined by framework classes.

Comment: Thats what I found out, i cannot even print the frame using the [ ] method you've shown.  Why did apple do this to us?

Comment: If what I showed doesn't work, you might be using a developer preview version of Xcode.  Try switching back to Xcode 4.5.2 and it should work.

Answer (score 6):

You can get it to print by doing [] notation instead of . notation:

Have you tried this?

```
print (CGRect)[textfieldObj frame]
```

Without the (CGRect) cast, it will most likely show an error saying that it doesn't know the return type. You can also just do:

```
po textfieldObj
```

which will show you the frame and some other information about the text field. the po debug command will call the objects -description method, which you can override to provide any information you like.

Answer (score 3):

See [An @import-ant Change in Xcode](http://furbo.org/2015/05/11/an-import-ant-change-in-xcode/)

> LLDB’s parser for Objective-C can now go through any module used in
>   your app and determine the types used for all functions and methods it
>   defines

```
e @import UIKit;
po uiTextFieldObj.frame
```